# Can secondary navigation be dynamic based on the page you are on?

Tags: navigation

Consider this page "WHO WE ARE", it shows photos of the management team. Notice the secondary level navigation on the left.

[image]

Now imagine, I click the photo of John and go down to a new page called "John" and I want the ability to drill down to other John-related pages.

My question is whether the secondary level navigation should always stay exactly the same no matter how far I go down? Or can I replace it each time with a new lower-level secondary navigation that is appropriate to the page, like below...

[image]

It feels great to be able to keep the secondary navigation on each page only specific to the page I am on, but feel that this is a misuse of what secondary level navigation actually is.

Note: This is just an example, I'm interested in the uses and misuses of secondary navigation. John and all his unnecessary pages which could just easily be tabs on a single page do not exist :)

Answer (score 1):

Secondary navigation should be relevant to the page the user is currently looking at. So If I'm in John's Detail page, secondary navigation should show me sections within John's Detail page.

You can always provide a Back button to the Parent aka Who We Are Page.

Alternatively, John's detail page can kill the About Us sec. nav and use tabs across for each section within John. Remember that About Us nav has nothing to do with John so shouldn't be there.